# Is there a good approach to deal with spacing as a first class design construct?

Tags: white-space

I am interested in a seasoned designer's advice on how to deal with the technical aspects of spacing. This applies to typesetting software, document design software, or even CSS on a website or web app.

Whenever I start building a design system, I usually end up with a very disorganized spacing design approach. For example, one may wish a level 3 header to have a certain amount of padding or margin above and below it. However, this is context dependent in more complicated documents.

I always end up with what I consider to be a hack, where I haphazardly apply different top and bottom padding conventions given the context. I've often felt that simply designing with "space" as a design element, as apposed to being indirectly linked to padding and margin of other elements would solve this problem.

Does anyone have a good reference or system style advice for dealing consistently with spacing? I'm more interested in technical solutions, not so much theory of spacing (Law of Proximity, for example). I work mainly in CSS and Scribus.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE. This is an interesting but very broad question. As I read it I started imagining giving a very broad answer focusing on [Gestalt psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology) and the law of proximity. In the end you state you are not looking for theory but technical solutions. Since you already know about the theory and you know how to apply space, I'm unsure what kind of answer you are expecting. Different approaches can be fitting for different contexts. For example working with layouts using baseline grid has its own set of challenges.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question, but indeed a bit broad. This, more than an answer is a long comment.

> one may wish a level 3 header to have a certain amount of

**1.** Remember that you need to separate structure to style. You *need* an h3 to specify that level of structure, not a stylish decision.

> padding or margin above and below it.

**2.** Try to limit the usage of just one of them. I normally do not ever use margin. I always assign **border-box** to all elements.

I'm a simple person, and for me, it is easier to understand the external border as my absolute boundary, the same as people did since the Mechanical movable type printing was invented centuries ago, and start reducing the elements inside this page.

> haphazardly apply different top and bottom padding conventions given the context.

**3.** It is not bad to have different top and bottom paddings. Just define what is the element that is changing the convention. Is it really the h3? or it is the image below it. If the image is unique, then, define different top padding to the container of it, not tho the h3.

One function of styling is not only to make it look nice but to give consistency to the lecture of a long document. This help us categorize.

---

**4.** In unique elements, we, of course, need an optical adjustment. Probably there is a mathematical solution to it, but for now, it is a matter of just looking and taking decisions. That is why we need designers in the first place. <sub>That is until AI replace us all</sub> :o), and even then we need to stay relevant as decision-makers.

Answer (score 1):

(Working with InDesign) I've been faced with both ways to approach this, and found both ways useful depending on the type of work:

1. Highly rigid work, where each style is 100% always sticking to its definition. That means, no style overrides whatsoever. Financial documents, scientific, legal and generally text heavy work usually require this type of formatting.
2. Flexible work, where the client prefers a more 'breaking the grid' approach, in which case, a good part, or the entire, typesetting and spacing is custom made, with medium to zero re-usage of existing styles. More marketing-oriented material, brochures, magazines or small one-pagers tend to justify for this approach, when you've either got too much variation in content, or the item is too basic to justify for actually having styles in place.

Based on the above, I think consistency should be built and applied per client, instead of trying to follow some very general rule of formatting for everything you do.

I have personally just closed a job recently where my initial approach was to go for a #1-type very repetitive style-heavy design, which was turned around by the client who actually needed a more playful, #2-type approach, which eventually made most of the formatting locally adjusted.